# Hibernate: how to create a constraint with two columns (field) of the same table (or entity)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, relational-database

I have an hibernate entity which contains two dates: `start` and `finish`.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{ 

    private Date start
    private Date finish;
    ...
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "start", nullable = false)
    public Date getStart() {
        return start
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "finish", nullable = false)
    public Date getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }
}
```

I would like to introduce a constraint that says `start` must be before `finish`, 
can I do this kind of validation/check in the hibernate entities in order to avoid to write invalid data in  my table? 
 
If yes, how?
My guess is not, probably I have to write a trigger.. is it right? any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/preface.html) to add vlaidation for your entities. You need to introduce your own [custom constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html).

Or you can do it manually in your DAO layer:

```
public class MyEntityDAO{ 

    ....

    protected void save(MyEntity entity) {
      // check dates
      // throw some exception in a case of problems
      getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
}
```

As a downside this will not work if you save some parent entity and `MyEntity entity` will be saved by cascade.

An easier to do solution may be using `@PrePersist`:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{ 

    ....

    @PrePersist
    protected void checkDates() {
      // check dates
      // throw some runtime exception in a case of problems
    }
}
```

But I am not sure that in this case trnsaction will be rolled back by default.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Maksym for @PrePersist suggestion, just taking the idea further.

You can also use  @PrePersist with @EntityListeners to handle the entity validations:

```
public class MyEntityValidationEventListener {
   @PrePersist
   public void validate(Object entity) {....}
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityValidationEventListener.class)
public class MyEntity {...}
```

Comment: +1 thnaks for sharing. It will give you ability to separate your entity (POJO) and validation code